# LVM allocations change after restart

Tags: 11.10, lvm

I have been running Ubuntu as a dual boot with XP on a caddy.  I also run XP in a VirtualBox guest.  My last upgrade to Natty worked fine and automatically mounted all of my internal drives (13 partitions).

I have upgraded to 11.10 and, because it doesn't automatically mount  all of my drives, I am having all sorts of problems.  If I cold boot the machine, fdisk -l tells me the allocations to sda, sdd etc but, if I restart (warm boot), all of these allocations change.  What was on sda is now on sdc and sdc is now sde and so on.

I want to (am running) Virtualbox with the vdi on  what is sdc1 at boot up.  At the moment, if I set up fstab to auto mount sdc1 with these settings and then restart, I get all sorts of errors.
Is there any way to force LVM or whatever to maintain the allocations through a restart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Mount partitions by UUID](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-finding-using-uuids-to-update-fstab/) to solve the problems of disk drives changing
their device name.

You can find out the UUID of a disk device with the [blkid](http://manpages.ubunut.com/blkid) command:

```
$ sudo blkid -p /dev/sda1
/dev/sda1: UUID="af340d98-0e91-4990-8cc9-17566264db2b" VERSION="1.0" TYPE="ext4" USAGE="filesystem"
```

Then you can replace the `/dev/sda1` line in `/etc/fstab` with the
UUID=... version.  For instance:

```
UUID=af340d98-0e91-4990-8cc9-17566264db2b  /  ext4 rw,errors=remount-ro
```